# What is the difference between ending a question with んだ？and の？

Tags: word-choice, usage, nuances, particles

I thought の when used in questions is for when you’re asking for an explanation or to have a curious tone, but んだ is also for explanation and I’ve seen both used to end questions so what are the differences between them?

Comment: Once crucial difference is that generally, んだ can only end a WH-question (what, when, where, how, who).

Comment: @AeonAkechi We can say `見たんだ?`...

Comment: @naruto Not a native speaker, but doesn't that have a different nuance from 「見たの？」At any rate, that's why I said 'generally'.

Answer (score 5):

For **yes-no type questions**:

> 1. 食べたの？
> 2. 食べたんだ？

Sentence 1 is very common, and sounds friendly and neutral (i.e., you have no prior assumption). Syntactically, sentence 2 may not be a question, but with a question mark, it sounds more like a confirmation with a surprised and/or accusatory tone ("So...you ate it, is that right?").

[image]

For **wh-type questions** (どこ, 何, etc):

> 3. どこへ行くの？
> 4. どこへ行くんだ？

Sentence 3 is a simple, gender-neutral, colloquial question. Sentence 4 sounds masculine (or sometimes militaristic), blunt and often oppressing. You usually don't have to say a sentence like 4 even to your family.

[image] [image]